# Using safe mode to get char** from dll (Passed as (IntPtr) parameter to the function)

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a dll to which I pass a `char**` pointer:
I can do that as following in VS 2010 c# unsafe mode:

```
public unsafe void loadParamListFromWks()
{
    char** list = null;
    dllFunctionGetList((IntPtr)(&list));

    int i = 0;
    IntPtr ptr;
    while ((ptr = (IntPtr)parameterNames[i]) != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr));
        i++;
        ptr = (IntPtr)parameterNames[i];
    }
}
```

As you see the dll populates an array of string (list) that I will use after in my code
How can I do that in safe mode?
I hope to get a short simple approach.

Comment: Looks like you did not declare the function parameter correctly, it should be `out IntPtr`.  Use Marshal.ReadIntPtr() to read the array elements.  You need unspecified magic to know how many elements are in the array and how to deallocate the memory for it.   Odds for success are not good.

Comment: @Hans Passant 1 , actually this call works very fine now. with reference to the dll and some usings

Comment: Yup, famous last words.  Given the high odds for a memory leak, consider actually testing for this so you can be *sure* you don't have a leak.  Write a little test program, call the function a billion times.

Comment: Leaks, my function is same as show above, i'm allocating any memories, sure the dll (black box for me) is doing it, should i care about freeing the memory used by the returned string list (list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below way, if you want to avoid `unsafe`.

Use DLL import attribute.

Use the namespace  `System.Runtime.InteropServices`

Also for different calling conventions in DLL import attribute refer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx

(Rough code. Not tested)

```
//DECLARE THE FUNCTION FROM DLL
[DllImport(<<YOUR DLL>>,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void dllFunctionGetList(IntPtr[] ListOfStrs);

//GET THE LIST OF STRINGS
IntPtr[] parameterNames = new IntPtr[100];
dllFunctionGetList(parameterNames);

int i = 0;
IntPtr ptr;

//ITERATE THE STRINGS
while ((ptr = (IntPtr)parameterNames[i]) != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i see you fixed parameterNames to 100 entries, this list can actually vary from few to few thousands, is it possible to make it variable size, dllFunctionGetList will populate it and only it know after run how much strings (char*) are inside.

Comment: For that see if you can have another function that returns the number of strings from DLL. Then first get the length. Declare your IntPtr[] based on the known length.

Comment: Thank you very much i consider this as the accepted answer. i will keep using safe mode since i don't have information about the returned list size.

Comment: Also probably you may recommend the library vendor to write a get function to return number of strings. It is just a simple thing for them...

Comment: meant keep using unsafe mode in my previous comment